# сравнение массива с массивом

Tags: c++

Помогите получить запись для редактирования в case 3

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma argsused

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <stdio.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <conio.h>

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
struct TZap {
    char FIO[30];
    int god_r;
    int n_gr;
    int ocen_fiz, ocen_mat, ocen_inf, ocen_him;
    double s_b;
} Zap;

int size = sizeof( TZap );
FILE *Fz, *Ft;
char File_Zap[] = "zapisi.dat";
char File_Rez[] = "rezult.txt";
void Out( TZap );

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    int kod, D_f, i = 0, j, kol, x, xx;
    int check = 1;
    long len;
    TZap st, *mas_Z;
    Ft = fopen( File_Rez, "w" );
    char fio_edit[30];

    while( true ) {
        puts( "\n\n 1 - Create\n 2 - Add\n 3 - Edit\n 4 - View\n\n 0 - Exit" );
        printf( "\n\t" );
        scanf( "%d", &kod );

        switch( kod ) {
            case 1:
                if( ( Fz = fopen( File_Zap, "wb" ) ) == NULL ) {
                    puts( "\n Create ERROR! Press any key!" );
                    getch();
                    continue;
                }

                fclose( Fz );
                printf( "\n Create New File %s !\n", File_Zap );
                break;

            case 2:
                Fz = fopen( File_Zap, "ab" );
                printf( "\n F.I.O. - " );
                fflush( stdin );
                printf( "\n\t" );
                gets( Zap.FIO );
                printf( " Year of birth - " );
                printf( "\n\t" );
                scanf( "%d", &Zap.god_r );
                printf( " Group number - " );
                printf( "\n\t" );
                scanf( "%d", &Zap.n_gr );
                printf( " Physics - " );
                printf( "\n\t" );
                scanf( "%d", &Zap.ocen_fiz );
                printf( " Mathematics - " );
                printf( "\n\t" );
                scanf( "%d", &Zap.ocen_mat );
                printf( " Computer science - " );
                printf( "\n\t" );
                scanf( "%d", &Zap.ocen_inf );
                printf( " Chemistry - " );
                printf( "\n\t" );
                scanf( "%d", &Zap.god_r );
                printf( " Mark - " );
                printf( "\n\t" );
                scanf( "%lf", &Zap.s_b );
                fwrite( &Zap, size, 1, Fz );
                fclose( Fz );
                break;

            case 3:
                if( ( Fz = fopen( File_Zap, "rb" ) ) == NULL ) {
                    puts( "\n Open ERROR! Press any key!" );
                    getch();
                    continue;
                }

                printf( "\n Vvedite F.I.O." );
                fflush( stdin );
                printf( "\n\t" );
                gets( fio_edit );
                Fz = fopen( File_Zap, "rb" );
                D_f = fileno( Fz );
                len = filelength( D_f );
                kol = len / size;
                mas_Z = new TZap[kol];

                for( i = 0; i < kol; i++ ) {
                    fread( ( mas_Z + i ), size, 1, Fz );
                }

                fclose( Fz );

                for( int i = 0; i < kol; ++i ) {
                    for( int j = 0; j < 30 && mas_Z[i].FIO[j] != '\0' && fio_edit[j] != '\0' &&
                            check; ++j )
                        if( mas_Z[i].FIO[j] != fio_edit[j] ) {
                            check = 0;
                            printf( "Ne sovp" );
                        }
                }

                //printf(" Edit:\n 1 - F.I.O\n 2 - Year of birth\n 3 - Group number\n 4 - Physics\n 5 - Mathematics\n 6 - Computer science\n 7 - Chemistry\n 8 - Mark\n");
                break;

            case 4:
                if( ( Fz = fopen( File_Zap, "rb" ) ) == NULL ) {
                    puts( "\n Open ERROR! Press any key!" );
                    getch();
                    continue;
                }

                printf( "\n\t--------- Informations ---------\n" );
                fprintf( Ft, "\n\t--------- Informations ---------" );

                while( 1 ) {
                    if( !fread( &Zap, size, 1, Fz ) ) {
                        break;
                    }

                    Out( Zap );
                }

                fclose( Fz );
                break;

            case 0:
                fclose( Ft );
                return( 0 );
        }
    }

    return( 0 );
}

void Out( TZap z )
{
    printf( "\n %20s, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %1f\n\n\t", z.FIO, z.god_r, z.n_gr,
            z.ocen_fiz, z.ocen_mat, z.ocen_inf, z.god_r, z.s_b );
    fprintf( Ft, "\n %20s, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %1f\n\n\t", z.FIO, z.god_r,
             z.n_gr, z.ocen_fiz, z.ocen_mat, z.ocen_inf, z.god_r, z.s_b );
    getch();
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, почините ваш форматировщик кода. Или не откатывайте правки, которые приводят исходники в читаемый вид.

Comment: Ознакомьтесь с информацией о том как получить [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i<kol; ++i)
    if (strcmp (mas_Z[i].FIO, fio_edit)==0){
        x = i;
        break;
    }
    else
        x=-1;
if(x == -1)
    puts ("\tSovpadenii net");
```

Answer (score 3):

Вы пытаетесь сравнить массив символов с одним символом, я так понял вам нужен следующий код:

```
char fio_edit[30];
int check = 1;
for(int i = 0; i<kol; ++i){
   for(int j = 0; j < 30 && mas_Z[i].FIO[j]!='\0' && fio_edit[j]!='\0' && check; ++j)
      if(mas_Z[i].FIO[j]!=fio_edit[j]){
        check=0;
        printf("Не совпадает");
      }
}
```

Данный код пробегает по двум массивам символов и ищет первый символ, который не совпадает.

Comment: ровно то же самое делает [std::mismatch](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/mismatch/)

Comment: @Евгений, поправил, предполагалось, что остальной код сами допишите

Comment: @komdosh  Смотрите мой ответ и учитесь